# Command to List all files and filesizes contained in folders that match a specific name?

Tags: cmd, directory, command-prompt

I would like to print all file names and sizes of files that are located in any folder that matches "alpha".

I understand `dir /s` will print all file names and sizes of the entire directory and sub directories recursively, but don't know how write a command to only display contents of folders which match a specific string (in my case **alpha**) in their file path.

for example if this is my directory:

```
C:\Users\raigovind93\Documents\1\alpha\doc1.txt
C:\Users\raigovind93\Documents\2\1\1\alpha\doc2.pptx
C:\Users\raigovind93\Documents\2\1\1\alpha\apple\doc3.xslx
```

I would like to print:

```
doc1.txt 20020 bytes
doc2.pptx 102002 bytes
doc3.xslx 289 bytes
```

And for clarity sake, if you can show both an answer that shows folders along with file names (to verify correctness of the command) and one without folders, that will be super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
dir /s |find /I "\alpha\"
```

You can use 'find' with the pipe on other commands too.

Comment: Hi Jim, I tried this command..it seems to reach the alpha folder but does not print the contents inside the alpha folder.

Comment: The search string should read `\alpha\ `, because `alpha` would also match directories like `alphabet`, erroneously; furthermore, add the `/I` switch to find in order to treat file names case-insensitively, which is also the native way of Windows to treat file paths/names...

Answer (score 0):

on command line:

```
for /r %a in (*) do @echo %a %~za bytes|find /i "\alpha\"
```

for use in batchfiles, double the percent-signs:

```
for /r %%a in (*) do @echo %%a %%~za bytes|find /i "\alpha\"
```

see `for /?` for details.

Comment: Stephan where in the command would you specify a file path? I'm working with a mapped drive, so I am never in the directory itself.

Comment: Also, when i executed the command, I got a bunch of `blah is not recognized as an internal or external command` (where blah seems to be the the first word of file names) error messages, so there seems to be something wrong with the command.

Comment: For the start path use `for /r "y:\server path\" %a in (*) do ...` or `for /r "\\123.123.123.123\server path\" %a in (*) do ...`. Can't reproduce your errormessage.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dir /B /S /A:-D` to return all files (`/A:-D`) in the current working directory recursively (`/S`) as a bare list (`/B`), then pipe (`|`) the result into `find /I "\alpha\"` to filter for items that contain `\alpha\` in their paths case-insensitively (`/I`); then parse its output by a `for /F` loop:

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %F in ('dir /B /S /A:-D ^| find /I "\alpha\"') do echo %~nxF %~zF bytes
```

To include the full paths in the returned items, replace `%~nxF` by `%~fF`.

Remember to double the `%` signs to use this command line in a batch file.

Comment: This is very close! I need their filesizes as well (part of question)!